# Redirect to CDN

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, cdn

I have a wordpress installation on bitnami. I am trying to setup a CDN for the contents of the wp-content folder. The CDN utilizes AWS Cloudfront with all the contents of the wp-content folder in an S3 bucket.
I can't get apache to redirect any requests for the assets to the CDN. I have tried quite a few things but I just can't get it to work.

contents of htaccess.conf file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.png$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://site.cloudfront.net/$1 [NC,NE,R=301]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
</FilesMatch>
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
# Expires Caching End #

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/akismet">
# Only allow direct access to specific Web-available files.

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Akismet CSS and JS
<FilesMatch "^(form|akismet)\.(css|js)$">
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Akismet images
<FilesMatch "^(.+)\.(png|gif)$">
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Allow from all
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# compression
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#</ifModule>
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files
</Directory>
```

Contents of http-app.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    # Added the following 3 lines to force https
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
    #RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ https://site.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/$1 [P]
    #Redirect permanent /wp-content/ https:/site.cloudfront.net/wp-content/
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/www.site.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/www.site.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/www.site.crt"
    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Contents of httpd-app.conf

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.png$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://site.cloudfront.net/$1 [NC,NE,R=301]

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock|fcgi://wordpress-fpm" timeout=300>
    </Proxy>
</IfDefine>

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
# Added +Includes for CDN testing. KA
    Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks +Includes
# Change from None to All. KA
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
       <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://wordpress-fpm/"
       </FilesMatch>
    </IfDefine>


    RewriteEngine On
# Do not touch the lines below. Added for redierect to www. KA
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>

Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf"
```

If anyone notices any redundant code related to redirects then that's me testing to get this to work.

I can access the contents of the S3 bucket and the cloudfront URL outside the site with no issues.

Any solutions or pointers in the right direction would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'll write my response as an answer for code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you but as far as redirection goes:

When I redirect to https from the http version of my site I use this line in my apache2.conf file:

```
Redirect "/" "https://www.version.of.my.site"
```

I noticed your Redirect lines in your http-app.conf are commented out.

Comment: I have tried like a 100 different combinations but none of them have worked for me so far. The site redirects to https even from http with what I have at the moment.

Comment: @naerak Is there a forum for the CDN that you use? Maybe they would be more helpful. Also I didn't suggest to use what I posted above for redirecting from http to https. I was saying that this is how I redirect and perhaps you can use the same line of code to redirect in your apache config file. I see it up there in your virtual host but it's commented out.